# how to deploy a ruleApp contains xom that based on java jars to ilog execution server

Tags: java, wsdl, ilog, xom, jrules

I have an ilog jrules execution server 7.1 installed. 
and I want to deploy a ruleApp that contains xom **based on java jars**.
I don't know **where can I package my resources jar for the ilog server**?
when i deploy it from the rule designer it doesn't package the xom jars, and I get this exception when trying to retrieve the wsdl:
*"this ruleset cannot be parsed, It used Java XOM with complex types, which is not supported by the hosted transparent decision service"*

Answer (score 0):

The ruleApp will not contain XOM objects - it contains only the BOM objects and rules. You will need to package your XOM objects into a WAR file that's deployed as a web app on your app server.

Comment: is it regular java war? should I add some more descriptors files? Can you focus me to the right folder?

Comment: can I deploy this war/web app from the rule studio

Answer (score 0):

- From your development envirement, you can right click on the rules project (in rule studio) and choose deploy XOM to the RES server

**OR**

- You can connect to the RES console (the default webapp to administrate rules execution server: default url is YOUR_SERVER:YOUR_PORT/res) and add a ressource manually (in your case a zip containing the *.class compiled YOUR_LIB.zip)

==> You will get a ressource in your res console named YOUR_LIB.zip (usually versionned)

**THEN**

From your RES console, select your rule app -> Your Ruleset and add an URI to your ruleset (choose the library uploaded as URI: YOUR_LIB.zip)

Comment: It's not supported in 7.1